# Why can't I downvote comments?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting

I've always been curious about this. We can upvote questions, answers, and comments.

But we can only downvote questions and answers.

One situation in which comment downvoting would be helpful is if a commenter posts an obviously false response to the question or answer, like

> You can't create classes in PHP, it's not a object-oriented language

That's an incorrect statement, and currently the only way to combat obviously incorrect comments is replying like:

> @PHPNoob123 You can create classes, see [insert link here]

So what is the purpose of not allowing downvotes on comments? I understand that Stack Overflow strives to be a community focused on the positives, but there's got to be a more direct explanation for why.

Comment: I suppose it's because comments can't be wrong (when used correctly - he says, ironically using comments incorrectly). The only time I've wanted to down vote a comment was here on meta where things are a little less formal

Comment: Cross site dupe: [Should downvoting be allowed on comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/should-downvoting-be-allowed-on-comments)

Comment: @RichardTingle Are comments (more) formal on SO? In that case I've been doing it wrong all these years :p

Comment: @keyser You and me both, but still, there's the theory and then there's the practice

Comment: Ton's of comments are un-constructive, it would be nice to be able to downvote them.

Comment: Common misconceptions are over-represented as a result comments having no downvote.

Comment: This is an old discussion, but I'll add to it anyway rather than start a new one. I would wholly support downvoting comments. In my (admittedly anecdotal) experience, well more than 50% of the comments are not useful; they're overly opinionated, not responsive, and generally just waste time. Many are flat wrong. But the point is they are offered more carelessly than answers no doubt because there's no possibility of a downvote, and only the possibility of an upvote. I would allow downvotes with a small (1 or even 0.5, if possible) reputation loss.

Comment: Also, Stack Overflow wants users to be able to leave something on a post and not worry about their reputation changing. This is also the reason why comments don't give reputation. Stack Overflow also doesn't want everything to be tied to rep.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly that it should be possible to downvote comments, and have felt this way for a long time. If anything, it's *questions* that shouldn't be downvotable, because bad questions *can already be dealt with via closure*.

Comment: @MrPizzaGuy if Stack Overflow doesn't want everything to be tied to rep, then *why does it require a minimum level of rep before new users can even leave comments* (which has the frequently observable negative effect that they write answers when they shouldn't, and complain to you about the inability to comment when you lecture them about it)?

Comment: OK, so no downvote for comments ... how about a facepalm?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Because comments are not posts. They are just a "bonus", an addition to the post itself, which can be upvoted or downvoted.

As [Jon Skeet said on a related discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3620/152859):

> If a comment is wrong, respond to it with another comment. That provides a lot more information than a downvote which could mean anything.

That's about the only thing you can do, flagging comment just because it's wrong won't do any good, as [moderators will just decline such flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253178/why-cant-i-downvote-comments/253182?noredirect=1#comment192691_253182).

Comment: thanks, I usually see the responding to incorrect comments a lot. Just wondered if there was a more direct way to indicate such incorrectness.

Comment: Cheers, and no such way I fear. :)

Comment: Your last two sentences are totally incorrect. Moderators will not delete comments based on factual errors: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294107/19679 and will decline any flags like this.

Comment: @Brad while I disagree, I do understand - will edit.

Comment: Another problem with not being able to downvote comments is that sometimes provocative but inaccurate comments get a lot of upvotes, while the response to it below does not. To the casual observer, the wrong information looks right.

Comment: case in point: comments on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21311626/2119053

Comment: @jrharshath agree it's a problem. In such case, first step should be ask the comment author to remove the comment, explaining why. If he refuse, flag the comment, choose "Other" and explain in detail why it's harmful to keep it. If this also fails (flag declined) you can go to the relevant chat room, pledge your case in there, and if enough users agree with you, 5-6 ordinary flags (e.g. "not constructive") will also remove the comment automatically. Not ideal, not so nice, but will make things right.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion. Furthermore, it should be that a comment which is largely disagreed with by the community should be flagged as such, and not left as a semi-permanent seemingly upvoted slur, as comments often are it seems, on the asker's or (more rarely) answerer's record.

Comment: I don't understand how this is supposed to constitute a meaningful response. I don't see why the "bonus" status should be at all relevant to the argument, and the fact that moderators decline those flags frustrates me. There's a system in place used to democratize quality sorting on questions and answers. Comments can in principle be poor quality. The argument about replying to comments also applies equally well to answers, and downvoting a question ought to be accompanied by a comment since it otherwise could equally well "mean anything".

Comment: @KarlKnechtel you consider something you don't agree with as "not meaningful", which is common, but wrong. 51 people found it meaningful (I hope, or just randomly upvoted?) so you can't just say something like that because you don't find it useful and/or you don't agree with it. Anyway, comments and answers are not equal. Never were, and never will be. By their very definition, comments are less important than answers, and should be treated in different way.

Comment: "you consider something you don't agree with as "not meaningful"" No, I do not. I do not consider that an accurate representation of what I said at all. I think the response is not meaningful because it *fails to address obvious objections*.