# Flagging incorrect comments?

Tags: discussion

In the C++ question [Is it safe to use operator [] for std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30187915/2069064), the OP is asking for a way to pass a `std::string` into a function that takes a `char*`. There is a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187915/is-it-safe-to-use-operator-for-stdstring/30188026#comment48481228_30187915) on the question which reads:

> Why not use `s.c_str()`?

That's a very easy mistake to make, and is not a valid proposal. However, the comment has 3 upvotes (like I said, easy mistake), which might make it misleading to future readers. There are subsequent comments that indicate that this is invalid, and the commenter himself agreed.

Question is: would it be reasonable to flag this comment as **not constructive**? In a literal sense, the suggestion is not constructive to answering the question - but I've been using this flag more for off-topic snark. (Side-question: maybe we should just allow downvoting comments?)

Comment: There are a lot of upvoted incorrect comments out there, and flooding the moderators with flags on those does not look like a good idea. You can dispute that comment with your own comment, most of the time the "right" comment ends up with more votes than the "wrong" one (and the latter's author may delete it if they notice their blunder).

Comment: Keep in mind that comments are "second-hand" citizens, so they are inherently less reliable than posts.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That's not very convincing. There's a lot of unconstructive, chatty, obsolete, or spammy comments out there too and we're encouraged to flag those.

Comment: Indeed, and the moderators already have the hands full with those. IMHO adding a "wrong" comment flag would have the same effect as trying to use the NAA flag on wrong answers -- flags are just not meant for that.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I fail to understand why "don't bother the mods!" is *ever* a valid justification for not improving the quality of the information on the site.

Comment: @rwollr, improving the quality of the information on the site does not necessarily imply moderators should be involved. The rest of us have enough privileges to do the right thing, and as Brad pointed out, it scales a lot better than pretending moderators possess *an impossibly broad range of experience with all the technologies represented here*.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Moderators should not be burdened with the responsibility of judging whether comments offering advice are factual. That's a given. Rather, comments which try to be answers on their own should just be deleted as a rule, or transferred to the form of an answer where they can then receive community feedback in a visible way. I would appreciate a flag which suggests "promoting" the comment to a separate answer.

Comment: If the commenter agreed why didn't they delete the comment?

Answer (score 11):

People flag comments all the time using custom flags stating "this is incorrect" or "totally wrong". We decline almost all of these.

For the same reason that we don't delete answers when people flag them as being incorrect, it isn't our place to judge the technical correctness of comments. That would require an impossibly broad range of experience with all the technologies represented here.

We'll step in for rudeness, noise, nonsense, and spam, but moderators should not have to judge the technical correctness of comments.

Comment: *"but moderators should not have to judge the technical correctness of comments."* You're right, it's unreasonable to assume that moderators have the time to research every comment (or answer) flagged incorrect... which begs the question, why are comments not subject to the same crowdsourced judgement as the rest of the site? The obvious answer is that comments should not be used where an answer would be a better choice, but no one seems to have a problem with comments being used as the asker describes in this question.

Comment: @rwollr - If you're asking why comments can't be downvoted, that's [something that has been discussed before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253178/why-cant-i-downvote-comments). The community has been getting more protective of comments lately, so perhaps that's something that could be revisited. Community moderation of comments [has also been kicked around](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252691/135615), although usually in the context of dealing with noise, spam, and abusive comments.

Comment: I wasn't really proposing that, I was suggesting that if comments are going to be allowed as substitutes for answers (which they aren't supposed to) then they definitely need a downvote function. That's the reason supplied in the link for why they don't get to be downvoted. *However*, if comments acting as answers won't be deleted as they should then that point is moot. The problem, *really*, is that the comment the OP mentions is trying to be an answer, not just that it's wrong. Perhaps there should be a way to flag a comment for being transferred to the form of an answer instead.

Comment: Also, the accepted answer for the thread you linked directly contradicts what you are saying here. *"And I will add that if comment is outright wrong, flag it choosing "Other" and explain why it should be deleted. Good chance a moderator will delete it in such case."*

Comment: @rwollr - That answer was not written by a moderator, and is wrong. I've stated as much in a comment there.

Comment: So the answer is actually: if there is a **wrong** comment, the only thing one can do is add another comment and **hope** that this later comment gets upvotes, so that it is guaranteed to show up? I am with rw-nandemo here: a comment downvote would definitely help.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with @rw-nandemo. The *combination* of inability to downvote comments and inability to get them removed is *non-functional*. Please don't try to sell me on the idea that "making a correction and hoping it's more positively received" is an adequate solution, because *by that logic there is equally no need for the ability to downvote answers*.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the comment as it is clearly invalid, accepted as refuted in-thread, *and* an attempt to answer in the comments, while there exists a great answer **in the answers**.

Brad's reasoning still stands - given all the technologies we use, moderators can't be expected to know what's correct and incorrect, so expect such flags to be declined on those grounds.

However, if it's a half-baked attempt to answer, address the idea in an answer, refute it if apropos, then flag the comment as "no longer needed" or with a custom, "it's addressed in so-and-so's answer".