# What does upvoting a comment mean

Tags: discussion

When should I upvote a comment?

Is upvoting a comment because it is funny acceptable?

Why can't I downvote a comment?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment answers most of your questions. Voting in general is left up to users' discretion, but generally you would upvote something if it's useful.

Comment: On Metas, upvoting funny comments is generally par for the course. Elsewhere, comments generally need to be not merely funny but technically helpful in some more direct way ... although even on Meta, comments that satisfy this higher criterion tend to get more upvotes. Basically, the idea is to say, "Good point!"

Comment: Its a little personal when exactly you tag a comment (I can't call it an upvote since you can't downvote them); me personally I stick to what it technically achieves: when comment lists start to grow out of proportions, the site starts to hide the least tagged ones. So that's my basis for tagging a comment: I tag the ones I want to stay visible for as long as possible. I don't do it for many other reasons, I find it too much micro management. But that's only me.

Comment: You should put that as an answer @gimby

Comment: @Gimby That's what I tend to do as well.

Comment: On the main site, I usually upvote a comment when one already exists that says much the same thing as I would have.  This reduces clutter (avoids numerous repeated comments) and brings attention to comments with broader support.

Answer (score 21):

Voting (even on comments) differs from site to site.  Meta is a lot more relaxed on voting and comments than SO is.  "Not constructive" comments are hardly ever flagged and deleted on meta (and sometimes highly upvoted).  Meta votes don't affect reputation.  This is [designed to encourage people to actually post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277274/why-is-there-no-reputation-on-meta?lq=1) their true feelings about a topic and foster more well-rounded discussion.

On the main site, comments that survive tend to be rather constructive.  I personally flag comments more readily on the main site to keep them as on-topic as possible.

---

With these voting and commenting cultures in mind:

> When should I upvote a comment?

Whenever you feel like it, although most people upvote comments they agree with or find helpful.  It's pretty much the same as upvoting a post, but with slightly lower standards.

On meta, it's similar once you adjust for the lax culture of meta.  Both comments and votes happen more freely.

> Is upvoting a comment because it is funny acceptable?

On the main site, I personally advise against this.  Funny comments are often off-topic and distracting, and I wouldn't want to encourage that too much.  Flagging them as "not constructive" would be appropriate, but please don't go out of your way to flag them, especially on old posts with a bajillion views.  [Moderators handle all comment flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278927/could-high-rep-users-help-with-clearing-comment-flags), so flooding them with them is not great.  Unless the comments are *really* getting out of hand.

On meta, people can be silly.  Voting and comments are both more relaxed.  Many other people upvote funny comments, so you can too.

> Why can't I downvote a comment?

Comments are second-class citizens that are subject to deletion at any time.  The reason voting is so restricted on comments is to encourage people to post answers (or at least alternate comments) instead.  For more, see [Shadow Wizard's answer to this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253182/4320665).

---

For some decent example of comment voting.  Here are two SEDE queries:

- [50 highest voted comments on Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/349682/50-highest-voted-comments)
- [50 highest vote comments on meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/349682/50-highest-voted-comments)

Comment: Comments are subject to deletion, sure. But they are actually harder to get rid of than answers are. By design they were second class citizens, by implementation they most certainly are not.

Answer (score 1):

**Terminology**: I don't like to speak of "upvoting" an answer since you can't downvote them - I call it tagging a comment.

---

The following only applies to comments on SO, not meta.

Its subject to personal preference when exactly you tag a comment; I'm sure many people tag what they "like" but for me that would mean I would tag most comments which are any grade of helpful; that doesn't really help put order to the chaos.

So me personally I stick to what it technically achieves. When comment lists start to grow out of proportions, the site starts to hide the least tagged ones. So that's my basis for tagging a comment: I tag the ones I want to stay visible for as long as possible.

**Examples**:

A comment which adds a missing piece of an answer or corrects a mistake is a good example of something I would definitely tag.

A comment which I recently have explicitly stopped to tag (but I can't always help it) is a comment which responds to another comment, even if it is a major reality-check that gives a huge sense of satisfaction and puts tears of joy in my eyes. For the exact same result-driven reason; I want to prevent it happening that the awesome response comment stays visible indefinitely while the source comment eventually is automatically hidden. The awesome comment completely loses its value when you don't see what it responds to anymore.

Comment: I cannot suggest an edit - I **think** you 1st sentence should read " ... upvoting a comment ...: